# Interacting with iframe with empty src attribute

Tags: testing, iframe, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test an a page with an external component which contains a following iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="about:blank" ... >
```

This iframe has an empty body initially but is populated with content after some actions.
When trying to run the following piece of code:

```
.expect(myIFrameSelector().visible).ok()
.switchToIframe(myIFrameSelector())
.expect(firstRowSelector()).eql("Hello")
```

I receive the following error on line 3:

```
The content of the iframe in which the test is currently operating did not load.
```

I tried waiting for the contents to appear with wait() and I checked it with debug() too.

Any ideas what could be the problem?
I assume that this is because the content was probably populated using JS, so can I somehow tell testcafe that the content is actually ready?

Comment: Could you show a simple sample illustrating how exactly you populate the iframe body? TestCafe injects service scripts into every loaded page, including those inside iframes. Your content population logic might interfere with these scripts in some way, which might cause them to stop working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately I don't know how exactly it is populated because it's an external component and I'd have to dig a little deeper but it seems that it's exactly what happens. Even the root-hammerhead-shadow-ui div is not in the body because it has probably been overridden. 
As it looks like a tedious task, we decided not to test this part, it would mostly test the implementation of the external component and we actually can cover business cases of our application without interacting with this iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to wait and check if the document in the iframe is loaded using [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/).

For example:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const waitForIframeLoad = ClientFunction((iframeSelector) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var i = 0;
    var intervalId = null;

    intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
        var iframeElement = document.querySelector(iframeSelector);
        if (iframeElement
            && iframeElement.contentWindow
            && iframeElement.contentWindow.location.href !== 'about:blank'
            && iframeElement.contentDocument) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            resolve();
        }
        if (i > 60) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            reject(new Error('Iframe content loading timeout'))
        }
        i++;
    }, 1000);
}));

fixture`fixture`
    .page`http://example.com`;

test('test', async t => {
    const iframeSelector = '#simulatorFrame';

    await waitForIframeLoad(iframeSelector);

    await t
        .switchToIframe(iframeSelector)
        .click(Selector('button'));
});
```